# Union of intersection of families

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm studying Halmos' *Naive Set Theory*. In Section 9, *Families*, he (essentially) mentions a following exercise (on page 35).

> Exercise. If $\{A_i\}$ and $\{B_j\}$ are both nonempty families, then
> $(\bigcap_iA_i)\bigcup(\bigcap_jB_j)=\bigcap_{i,j}(A_i\bigcup B_j)$.

However, I think that this is wrong, and the equality should be replaced with inclusion, *i.e.*, LHS should be a subset of (**not** generally equal to) the RHS. Correct?

Comment: You may be missing the fact that the intersection on the righthand side is over **all** pairs of $i$ and $j$.

Comment: Yes, I can now see it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the equality is correct. Suppose that $x\in \bigcap_{i,j}(A_i\cup B_j)$. If $x\in A_i$ for all $i$, then $x\in \bigcap A_i$ and we are done. Otherwise, there exists $i$ with $x\not\in A_i$. As $x\in A_i\cup B_j$ for all $j$, it follows that $x\in B_j$ for all $j$, so $x\in\bigcap_jB_j$.

Comment: Thanks, that was clear!

Comment: Glad I could help :D